# citing company yearly reports in papers

Tags: citations, latex, bibtex

I am writing a conference paper and want to cite the following report by Symantec using Bibtex (https://www.symantec.com/security-center/threat-report). I am currently using @techreport which only needs author,title,institution, year and month, but I am having trouble getting the authors. At the end of the report it has team and contributors listed, are team considered the authors ? also is @techreport the right category to use or should I be using a different one ?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to use a corporate author.

Using Harvard referencing for an undergraduate course I did a few years ago I cited annual reports like this with no problems.

Taylor Wimpey, 2014. The Taylor Wimpey Annual Report, High Wycombe: Taylor Wimpey.

The Berkeley Group, 2014. The Berkeley Group Annual Report 2014, Cobham: The Berkeley Group.

Standard Life Investments, 2015. The UK Stewardship Code- Compliance and Contacts. [Online]
Available at:
http://www.standardlifeinvestments.com/governance_and_stewardship/the_uk_stewardship_code
/index.html
[Accessed 15 March 2015].

Key Note Reports, 2015. Bellway PLC. [Online]
Available at: https://www.keynote.co.uk/company-report/ownership/01372603
[Accessed 3 March 2015].

If it is a team of authors and you are adamant to put an author if there are many authors the Harvard system allows you to put Smith et al. even in the even reference list.

Microsoft word is great for references and should not be overlooked for a simple and effective referencing tool.

Comment: In many cases, it is, indeed, the corporation that has published the report, not the employees who work there. In such cases a corporate author is probably more correct than trying to figure out the individuals involved. This is especially true for "official" reports such as financial data.